# Integer roots of polynomial with irrational coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

**Definition:**
*$n$-th root free:*
 Let $\dfrac{p}{q}$ be in lowest terms and if $b=\left(\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^{\!1/n}$ for some$\ n\in\mathbb{N}$, $b$ is called $n$-th root free if $b$ *cannot* be expressed as $b=\dfrac{p'}{q'}\left(\dfrac{p''}{q''}\right)^{\!1/n}$ for relatively prime pairs $p', q'$ and $p'',q''.$

**Question:**
Prove or disprove that the following polynomial $f(x)$ does not have a integer root:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\in \mathbb{R}[x],$$
where
$(i) \; a_i\in\{\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\}\cup\{0\}$$\ \forall \ i=1,2,...,n-1$.
$(ii)\;a_n=1$; $a_0\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}.$
$(iii)\; a_i$ and $a_j$ are pairwise distinct for all $i\neq j$.
$(iv)\; $ Let $\dfrac{p}{q}$ be in lowest terms and if $a_i=\left(\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^{\!1/n}$ for some$\ n\in\mathbb{N}$; then $a_i$ is $n$-th root free.

**My Comments:**
$1.$ It seems to be true.
$2.$ I have proved it for polynomials up to $\deg(f)=4$ since their roots could be easily seen through the radical method.

$3.$ It seems quite a difficult task for $\deg(f)\geq 5$.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your (iv) condition doesn't parse. Please rephrase.

Comment: I don't know what "the $n$-th root free" is. Could you please define that term?

Comment: Glad my example is useful, but I still can't wrap my mind around $n$th root free. What are $p,p',p'',q,q',q''?$ All primes? Or are $p$ and $q$ relatively prime, $p'$ and $q'$ relatively prime, and $p''$ and $q''$ relatively prime? Maybe you could give an example of some numbers that are $n$th root free, and some that are not?

Comment: @AdrianKeister $p'\ \text{and} \ q'$ are relatively prime and $p''\ \text{and} \ q''$ are also relatively prime. For eg: $\frac{1}{3}\times 2^{1/3}$ is not a $3$-rd root free. whereas $(\frac{16}{125})^{1/6}$ is $6$th root free.

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't look to me like $3\sqrt{2}$ is square root free, is it?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes. Prof. $3\sqrt 2$ is not square root free.

Comment: Then my counterexample isn't one, because isn't $a_0$ supposed to be $n$th root free?

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad to be of some help!

Comment: When you say $p,q$ and $p',q'$ and $p'',q''$ are all relatively prime pairs, do any of those numbers themselves have to be prime? Or are they just integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false. Examine the function $f(x)=(x-\pi)(x-2)=x^2-(2+\pi)x+2\pi.$ Now neither $2\pi$ nor $-(2+\pi)$ are expressible as the $n$th root of rationals, so the definition of being $n$th root free is vacuously true. This polynomial therefore satisfies all criteria, but certainly has an integer root.

Comment: Thank You, prof. But I have to edit the question... as the intention was not this one. Sorry.

Comment: Well, let me know when you've edited.

Comment: How about now? I don't understand your condition (iv), so maybe this doesn't pass muster. But this function has a root at $x=3.$

Comment: Prof. Clearly my comment #$2$ does hold true for the question as the conditions are more stringent after that edit. Can you please have a look again?

Comment: Edited. Just need to examine irrationals that are not expressible in terms of radicals.